# If $b\leq 1 \leq a$ then $ b+a\geq 1+ba$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a,b>0
$

The solution of a book Iread says so if you want I can add the context. Please help me to understand this Formula.

It is not obvious to me

I would understand $b+a\geq 1+a$ But when I multiply $a$ with $b$ the sum must get bigger(or eq) because $b\geq 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to $$(b-1)(1-a)\geq 0$$